# How can I convert a string to array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, object

I have a string like this:

```
$str = '[{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABB0pg6HTwdv7EqUBAAEC","file_size":1347,"file_path":"photos\/file_2.jpg","width":90,"height":75},{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABIMbRhad2WVdE6UBAAEC","file_size":17588,"width":320,"height":265},{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABHSo-WKlRRfBEaUBAAEC","file_size":18480,"width":330,"height":273}]';
```

How can I access items in it?

---

I can use regex to select them, something like `/"file_id":"(.*?)"/`. But that's not clean at all. Is there any approach to make a array (or an object) of string above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a json string.
You need to decode it with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
The second argument (true) is to make it an array.

```
$str = '[{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABB0pg6HTwdv7EqUBAAEC","file_size":1347,"file_path":"photos\/file_2.jpg","width":90,"height":75},{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABIMbRhad2WVdE6UBAAEC","file_size":17588,"width":320,"height":265},{"file_id":"AgADBAADX6oxGyqs0FJLW3rZ3g6_fDnO-RkABHSo-WKlRRfBEaUBAAEC","file_size":18480,"width":330,"height":273}]';


$arr = json_decode($str, true);
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/9BFIC

Comment: Thank you pal ...!

Comment: @Martin no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Explode(“,{”, $str); will work for the above.

You will get array value for each file.

Comment: This is a very bad solution. It is a json string and should be handled as such. Exploding like you suggest results in an array containing unusable strings